# How to DB query and then check the result

Tags: postgresql, go

I need to check if my query returns true or false. If it returns false, I want it to error out. Here is my code:

```
func (dr *dbrepo) checkIfUnique(datacenterstring) error {
    statement := `select exists(select 1 from source where datacenter = $3)`

    _, checkIfExists := dr.db.Query(statement)
    if checkIfExists != nil {
        log.Print("Error  is not unique", checkIfExists)
        return checkIfExists
    }
    return nil
}
```

The problem is: I think I need to convert `checkIfExists` from a row to a bool and then see if it is true or false. But I am not sure on how to do that. Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `var exists bool; err := dr.db.QueryRow(statement, args...).Scan(&exists); // check error and then check exists`. Your query has a parameter placeholder `$3` however you're not passing any args to the func, that will result in an error, also the fact that you have one placeholder but its ordinal number is `3` instead of `1` is strange and probably will result in an error no matter how many args you pass in.

Comment: Also, never discard the `*sql.Rows` value returned from `Query` or else your app will run out of connections. This is because the rows value must be explicitly closed by the caller.

Answer (score 2):

`Query()` does not return true or false. It returns two values: `*Rows` & `error`.

```
func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error) {
    ...
}
```

In your case: `checkIfExists` is the error. With this error, you can already tell of the query succeeded or failed. Like you do it:

```
if checkIfExists != nil {
    return checkIfExists
}
```

If you want more information (*such as the rows retrieved by your query*), then you will need to replace the `_` with a variable. Let's call it `rows` and then you use `rows.Scan()` to copy the data in the columns to your destinations. See `database/sql` [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) for more information.

Comment: "Every call to Scan, even the first one, must be preceded by a call to Next." https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Next. For result sets with a single row, such as this one, [QueryRow(Context) is simpler to use](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_QueryRowContext).

Comment: The problem I am having with the query is that it either returns t or f. So, it will always succeed. How can I use rows.scan to tell me that it is false?